# How to keep on hover properties active after moving off the element within a certain range?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've set up a menu as pictured in the snippet below. I want the user to be able to hover over the central icon and then be able to select one of the buttons on the side. I've had some success by placing another, larger element in front of the icon when the icon is hovered on and then chaining some hovers together but then as soon as they hovered over a button all the other ones disappeared. I've also tried expanding the padding of the #navCont element but the buttons disappear when hovering over any of them (it also pushes all my content up if I expand the bottom area)

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
}

#navCont {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

#sqlogo {
  opacity: .75;
  width: 3em;
  animation: pulse 1.8s cubic-bezier(.28, 0, .55, 1) 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
}

#sqlogo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#navCont .btn {
  opacity: .75;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#navCont:hover img.btn {
  display: block;
}

#navCont .btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#navCont #btnWork {
  left: 4em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#navCont #btnAbout {
  right: 4em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#navCont #btnContact {
  top: 4em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="title"> Title </div>
    <div id="navCont">
      <img id="sqlogo" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nybF_-lqMK9k0_X8EfgU8tKbiIzM459U" />
      <img id="btnWork" class="btn" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1o2pds3XK3Wh78pQPfC5cgsqWRHEIHy-Q" />
      <img id="btnAbout" class="btn" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1XGf88jotbT8n4NmBPc979gI1oYbhjgXb" />
      <img id="btnContact" class="btn" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1EjimLtnyIZRsfPbX3yc2wJ_s1Qxpwj45" / />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZDam.jpg

Ideally, I'd like the buttons to remain active while the cursor is in this area (see link above) after they have appeared via the icon, however, a rectangular area of that size would also be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an on hover event on your squid icon using javascript that when triggered keeps the menu content visible until a mouseout event on some larger parent area is triggered

Something like this:

```
   document.getElementById("sqlogo").onmouseover = function(){
      // show the buttons
      getElementsByClassName("btn").style.display = "block"
   };
   document.getElementById("navCont").onmouseout = function(){
      // hide the buttons
      getElementsByClassName("btn").style.display = "none"
   };
```

You might have to undo some of your CSS so that JS controls the visibility instead of CSS :hover

Comment: thanks. I decided to make use of the visibility to see If I could get the opacity trasitions working

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using JQuery. I just toggled the button visibility if the mouse didn't move to them fast enough after leaving the main icon

```js
$("#sqlogo").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#sqlogo").addClass("freeze");
  $(".btn").addClass("vis");
});

let t;

$("#sqlogo").mouseleave(function() {
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#sqlogo").removeClass("freeze");
    $(".btn").removeClass("vis");
  }, 500);
});

$(".btn").mouseenter(function() {
  clearTimeout(t);
});
$(".btn").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#sqlogo").removeClass("freeze");
  $(".btn").removeClass("vis");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
}

#navCont {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

#sqlogo {
  opacity: .75;
  width: 3em;
  animation: pulse 1.8s cubic-bezier(.28, 0, .55, 1) 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
}

#sqlogo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#sqlogo.freeze {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#navCont>.btn {
  opacity: .75;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
}

#navCont>.vis {
  visibility: visible;
}

#navCont>.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#navCont > #btnWork{
  left: 4em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#navCont #btnAbout {
  right: 4em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#navCont #btnContact {
  top: 4em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="title"> Title </div>
    <div id="navCont">
      <img id="sqlogo" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1nybF_-lqMK9k0_X8EfgU8tKbiIzM459U" />
      <img id="btnWork" class="btn" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1o2pds3XK3Wh78pQPfC5cgsqWRHEIHy-Q" />
      <img id="btnAbout" class="btn" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1XGf88jotbT8n4NmBPc979gI1oYbhjgXb" />
      <img id="btnContact" class="btn" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1EjimLtnyIZRsfPbX3yc2wJ_s1Qxpwj45" / />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```